# Azure API for Handwritten text is giving 202 error code

Tags: azure, computer-vision, handwriting-recognition, handwriting, digital-handwritting

I am able to use both of the Analyze Image and Describe Image APIs with no issues. However, the recognize handwriting API is giving me problems. I get a 202 Accepted response, but then when I go to the link provided in the operation-location field from the response header, I see this error:

{
error: {
code: "401",
message: "Access denied due to invalid subscription key or wrong API endpoint. Make sure to provide a valid key for an active subscription and use a correct regional API endpoint for your resource."
}
}

I tried with below link :

https://eastus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com

and got response :

Response status
202 Accepted

Response latency
133 ms
Response content
Pragma: no-cache
Operation-Location: https://eastus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v2.0/textOperations/6bbfc38e-c67e-4537-9814-62eaef16d81b
apim-request-id: 7d9e7188-d806-4d10-98fe-b8fd940e9390
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
x-content-type-options: nosniff
Cache-Control: no-cache
Date: Fri, 26 Jul 2019 10:01:40 GMT
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Content-Length: 0
Expires: -1